# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'

Tags: r, rstudio, rda

I am newbie to R and started doing Linear Regression in RStudio with a very simple code like the following:

```
dataset = load("C:\\pathToRDA\\swiss.RDA")

simple.fit = lm(formula = VoteYes ~ age,data=dataset)
```

The sample code loads in a RDA file which contains an object s in it.

After running this, I got a very common error:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) :  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
```

After googling for a while, I think the error has to do with the

```
data=dataset
```

part, since most similar errors that I got on Google is that the dataset is a String instead of a variable reference. But I think in my case dataset is not a String indeed, as in this tutorial:

[tutorial](http://www.learnbymarketing.com/tutorials/linear-regression-in-r/)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: @user5783745 Hi I tried that earlier, got error like: "Error in readRDS("C:\\pathToRDA\\swiss.RDA") : 
  unknown input format".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `load` directly

```
load("C:\\pathToRDA\\swiss.RDA")
#Assuming the dataset inside swiss.RDA is called swiss
simple.fit = lm(formula = VoteYes ~ age, data=swiss)
```

`dataset = load("C:\\pathToRDA\\swiss.RDA")` will create a varible in the *Values* section called `dataset` in your Global env with a string vlaue "swiss".

For example:

```
mtest = mtcats
save(mtest, file = "mt.rda")
mtc = load("~/mt.RDA") #Will create variable called mtc = "mtest" in Values in Global env.  
load("~/mt.RDA") #loads the mtest dataset
```